# javascript multilevel inheritance weird result

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype

I'm refreshing my javascript skills and came up with a way that objects can inherit from another.
The inheritance should be tree-like.

`Parent->Child->Child2`

I've extended the `Function.prototype` (Don't tell me this is a bad idea, this can be changed later)

```
Function.prototype.extend = function(child)
{
    // save child prototype
    var childPrototype = child.prototype;
    // copy parent to child prototype
    child.prototype = Object.create(this.prototype);
    // merge child prototype
    for (var property in childPrototype) {
        child.prototype[property] = childPrototype[property];
    }
    child.prototype.constructor = child;
    child.prototype.$parent = this.prototype;
    return child;
};
```

The parent object:

```
var Parent = (function()
{
    var Parent = function(x, y)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        console.log('Parent constr', x, y);
    }

    Parent.prototype.move = function(x, y)
    {
        this.x += x;
        this.y += y;
        console.log('Parent moved.');
    };

    return Parent;

}());
```

First child:

```
var Child = Parent.extend(function()
{
    var Child = function(x, y)
    {
        this.$parent.constructor(x, y);
        console.log('Child constr');
    }

    Child.prototype.print = function()
    {
        console.log('Child print', this.x, this.y);
    };

    // override
    Child.prototype.move = function(x, y)
    {
        this.$parent.move(x, y);
        console.log('Child moved.');
    };

    return Child;

}());
```

Second child:

```
var Child2 = Child.extend(function()
{
    var Child2 = function(x, y)
    {
        this.$parent.constructor(x, y);
        console.log('Child2 constr');
    }

    // override
    Child2.prototype.move = function(x, y)
    {
        this.$parent.move(x, y); // call parent move
        console.log('Child2 moved.');
    };

    return Child2;

}());
```

So far, so good. I'm able to call the parents constructor and methods and even override methods.

```
var child = new Child2(1, 1);
child.move(1, 1);
child.print();
```

I get following output which is correct:

```
Parent constr 1 1
Child constr
Child2 constr
Parent moved.
Child moved.
Child2 moved.
Child print 2 2
```

But if I comment out the override from second child I get following output:

```
Parent constr 1 1
Child constr
Child2 constr
Parent moved.
Child moved.
Child moved. -> WHY??
Child print 2 2
```

I don't understand why `Child moved.` is outputted twice. The result is correct but something weird is going on.

EDIT:

Finally after researching and diving more into the problem I came with a nice solution:

```
// call method from parent object
Object.getPrototypeOf(Child2.prototype).move.apply(this, arguments);
```

I made another extension to `Function`:

```
Function.prototype.getParent = function()
{
    return Object.getPrototypeOf(this.prototype);
};
```

And then for example the `Child2` move method:

```
Child2.prototype.move = function(x, y)
{        
    Child2.getParent().move.call(this, x, y);
};
```

So I don't need `$parent` anymore and I get the desired result.

Another solution would be to call the parent prototype directly:

```
Child2.prototype.move = function(x, y)
{        
    Child.prototype.move.call(this, x, y);
};
```

Comment: It's multilevel inheritance not multiple.

Comment: Exactly what part are you "uncommenting"? I don't see any code commented out.

Comment: @apsillers These are the properties from `childPrototype` -> `for (var property in childPrototype)`. So the check is not needed.

Comment: @apsillers The uncommenting is not in the post. I mean the whole function `Child2.prototype.move`.

Comment: Just so I'm clear, you mean "[comment out](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/33502/21286)" rather than "uncomment", correct? I haven't been able to reproduce your error in [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cFw4K/); could you edit and update that fiddle to demonstrate the error?

Comment: @apsillers yes this is correct. I get that error in chrome, firefox and ie10.

Comment: Stupid editing mistake on my part -- yes, I'm observing the error now.

Comment: The problem is that your instance `child` has its *own* move function which is copied reference to `Child.prototype.move`, which outputs "`Child moved`". The `child.move` function calls `this.$parent.move`. `child.$parent` is `Child`, and `Child.prototype.move` *also* outputs "`Child moved`". If the instance `child`  didn't have it's own copy of `move` this wouldn't be a problem, since `move` would cause a lookup up the prototype chain and call `Child.prototype.move` directly, instead of invoking indirectly as part of a call to `child`'s own `move` function.

Comment: To put it another way: `Child2.prototype.move` *is the same function* as `Child.prototype.move`. Because an instance of `Child2` has a `$parent` of `Child`, the `this.$parent.move` call in `move` causes a repeat call.

Comment: Due to the invocation of `this.$parent.move` in each of your subclasses `move` method `move` would get called `n+1` times *(where n is the level of inheritance)* anyway. With or without the code, commented out. As `child.move == Child2.prototype.move && Child2.prototype.move === Child.prototype.move`. If you would log `this.name + "Moved" ` instead of `"Child moved"` *(names assinged)*. You would see `Parent Moved, Child Moved, Child2 Moved` regardless of `Child2.prototype.move` commented out.

Comment: ok thanks to all, that makes sense. I'm trying out some things and will accept an answer later.

Comment: ignore previous comment! copying is happening, apologies for commenting before checking in a fiddle...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using apply to invoke your functions in the correct scope, also using `this` to access the parent is not safe. This is actually an excellent problem for learning about JS debugging, you can see everything happening using break points.

looking at your first Child :

```
// override
Child.prototype.move = function(x, y)
{
    this.$parent.move(x, y);
    console.log('Child moved.');
};
```

When this code is reached by calling `child.move(1,1)`, `this` points to `child`, and what does `child.$parent.move` point to? why, the implementation in the first Child of course!

This second time around, `this` points to the prototype of the Parent, so now we're fine.

So that's *why* this is happening, what can you do about it? Well that's up to you, I mentioned apply because that was my default thought, so you would use `this.$parent.move.apply(this, arguments);`, but then we *really* can't get access to higher parents, so the only other option I can think of is [binding](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) (hitching, for any dojo people reading) every function to it's respective prototype, thereby guaranteeing its `this` value always points to the same thing, and therefore it can always access the $parent reliably.

Of course, this would mean no access to the actual object instance, so it's only really useful for pure utility functions, but this is actually not new. If you had overridden print (which accesses the object instance's x and y members) and tried to invoke the parent, that would have broken as well.

Comment: I've tried it before with `this.$parent.move.call(this, x, y);` but that produce a stackoverflow.

Comment: yes, because you end up calling the same function again, as I said, this technique would give you access to the instance object, but no higher parents, so only viable for one level of inheritance.

Comment: Thank you, I accept your answer for a good explanation and trying to give a solution to the problem, although I haven't found one yet.

Comment: Well done! =) glad to see you found something that works for you =)

Answer (score 1):

Your extend method attaches the inherited properties and methods to the new object's prototype. It also creates a $parent object which is equal to the prototype of the parent object. Note that this results in duplication. The second child has three move methods:

```
child.protoype.move
child.$parent.move
child.$parent.$parent.move
```

Even if you comment out the override there are still three move methods (although two are references to the same function).

Therefore, when you run child.move you get:

`child.prototype.move` which invokes `child.$parent.move` which invokes `child.$parent.$parent.move`

The fact that child.prototype.move and child.$parent.move are both references to the same function does not prevent them from being executed twice.